# How to check using deferred values the ajax is complete or failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i check and wait for the server lag for the save function to complete, which returns an ajax object jqxhr, I want to check if the ajax request is complete or not before i do anything else else.

Note : the save function has success, complete errors etc.. I want to make sure its complete before i  do anything so that i dotn get undefined when i use jqxhr.status.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(function() {
            $("#save").click(function() {

             save().then(function(jqxhr){// check status...


                    alert(" jqxhr status " + jqxhr.status); <--getting undefined first
                    //200 for success
                    var stat = jqxhr.status;
                    //alert(" inside 200 status "+stat);
                    if (stat == 200) {
                        console.log("inside 200");

                        alert(" inside 200 status " + stat); 

                    }
                    if (stat == 400) {
                        console.log("inside 400");
                        alert(" inside 400 status " + stat);

                    } else {

                        alert(" inside 200 status " + stat);
                    }

                });

            });
        });
    });​
```

Comment: Just get used to the fact that this is **async** call. And you need to handle it accordingly. You *can* make xhr request a blocking call... **but** i would not recommend that at all, because it freezes the UI while waiting.

Comment: Why are you calling `save()`twice?

Comment: i need to get the value of jqxhr status the save function returns the jqxhr object. I am open to suggestion..I want to execute the if statements only after the ajax request is fully complete. How do wait or know the ajax request is complete..if I try to print jqxhr.status early i get undefined, sicne the ajax is not yet complete

Comment: user look at my answer. The request is mostly likely failing. Also can you post the code for you save() function ?

Comment: so basically what you are calling save() is just another name for $.ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save() function (which is actually just an ajax call) returns a promise, so you can use then() to chain your code:

```
save().then(function(jqxhr){// check status...});
```

Comment: How does it differ from passing success and failure callbacks? as soon as the chaining ends here, you get back to the code outside and it's going to be performed before the ajax request returns...

Comment: @poncha ok, I'll delete my answer as I am actually not clear what is behind save()

Comment: Undeleting my answer as the question now includes the save() function.

Comment: @poncha then() is meant to wait until the ajax request is returned and the success/error callbacks are executed.

Comment: ... but the success/failure callbacks themselves are also executed once the ajax has returned ;) the point is that the code outside this chaining will not wait, and i think the OP is not letting this issue rest ;)

Comment: @poncha maybe my answer is not clear, but the point is that the series of status checks (or whatever actually comes next) should go inside then(), not stay outside.